# C++ Polymorphism on Virtual Functions

Tags: c++, function, inheritance, polymorphism, virtual

I'm trying to figure out how inheritance and polymorphism is handled in C++, it seems its a little different than what I'm used to in Java. I'm trying to return a base class in one of the functions, but when the return is received, I would like the object to be the derived class. However it is not working out as expected for me.

```
#include "Prefixer.h"
using namespace std;

Prefixer::Prefixer( Lexer l ){
    lexer = l;
}

Expr Prefixer::expr() {
    Expr left = term();
    Expr right = termTail();
    cout << left.name();
    cout << right.name();
    return left;
}

Expr Prefixer::term() {
    NullExpr temp;
    return temp;
}

Expr Prefixer::termTail() {
    NullExpr temp;
    return temp;
}
```

But the returned left.name() and right.name() both calls the Expr's (the base class) virtual name() function :C. How can I make it so that they call the overloaded name() functions from the derived class NullExpr?

```
string Expr::name() {
    return "expr";
}

string NullExpr::name() {
    return "null";
}
```

Comment: Did you use "virtual " in Expr::name() method declaration?

Comment: @alexm: Wouldn't matter unless a pointer or reference is used to call the functions.

Comment: Re: "it seems its a little different than what I'm used to in Java" - A "little different" is quite an understatement. Pick up [a good introductory C++ book](http://tinyurl.com/so-cxxbooks) and it will make way more sense.

Comment: @Als - yes, thanks for the correction - overlooked slicing in this example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem starts in this code:

```
Expr Prefixer::term()
{
    NullExpr temp;
    return temp;
}
```

`temp` is a local variable, destroyed at the end of the function.  The return value makes an `Expr` instance (because that's the return type) by *copying* the return expression, `temp`.  The caller never sees a `NullExpr` object.

What Java does is essentially:

```
Expr* Prefixer::term()
{
    NullExpr* temp = new NullExpr;
    return temp;
}
```

but you mustn't blindly do that in C++, or you'll end up with memory leaks (Java has a garbage collector, C++ doesn't).  You can free the memory using `delete`:

```
Expr* left = term();
left->name();
delete name;
```

A more recommended approach is to use smart pointers that automatically destroy the object when the last pointer to it disappears:

```
shared_ptr<Expr> Prefixer::term()
{
    NullExpr* temp = new NullExpr;
    return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to make `left` and `right` be `Expr*` or `Expr&`, not `Expr`.

Unlike Java, variables of a class type in C++ hold actual instances, not references to instances.

So when you do:

```
Expr left = term();
```

you are actually calling `Expr`'s copy constructor, which will only make an instance of the base `Expr` class.

In Java, that's very different -- there you're just setting `left` to refer to some existing object, not creating a new.

Thus the need to have `left` and `right` be references or pointers -- so that the same thing happens in C++ that you're using to happening in Java.

Comment: Yep. Returning by value, rather than pointer or reference, leads to "slicing" of the object into the base type, the derived type is lost.

Comment: Not just the local variables, but also the return value, needs to be changed to avoid slicing.  Which means also introducing dynamic allocation.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I know the root of the problem now. However if I pass by value for the Expr left and right, how do I call the name() functions using left and right? right now I am getting an error like this:
error: request for member ?name? in ?left?, which is of non-class type (Expr*)

Comment: @Jason: To access members of a pointer, use `->`.  Like `left->name()`.

Comment: Thanks Ben, I remember that was one of the fundamental things I learned back when I first started C++, and now I've forgotten about it again ; ^;

Comment: There are a few other ways. For example, you can use a container that holds a value and copy-constructs it from its derived type when it's copied. [Boost::any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/any.html) is such a container. You can also use a container that holds `base*` and calls a virtual `duplicate` function to copy.

Answer (score 0):

To use the method `dynamic-binding`(or invoke overloaded subclass method with a handle to base object) you should manipulate object with reference or pointer. If implemented like that, make sure the life of your returned object is long enough, so you can access it after the method terminates. You find it's different from Java, because all object in Java is indeed a reference to a storage on heap, instead the object itself.